# Moduled actionButton with tryCatch and showNotification in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I create a moduled actionButton, I hope it can show the feedback to the users, that would be friendly.

1. In this example, it seemed not working after first success.
2. And I want to work with `withProgress`, but I don't know how long time the exact expression will take, I can't define the parameter `value`

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

friendlyAct <- function(id, label, icon = NULL, class = "btn-default") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(id, label, icon = icon, class = class)
}

friendlyActServer <- function(id, expr) {
  moduleServer(NULL, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    observeEvent(input[[id]], {
      tryCatch(
        withCallingHandlers(
          expr = expr,
          message = function(m) showNotification(m$message, type = "message"),
          warning = function(w) showNotification(w$message, type = "warning")
        ),
        error = function(e) showNotification(e$message, type = "error")
      )
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("event", "Event going to be test", choices = c("message", "warning", "error")),
  friendlyAct("test", "FriendlyActionButton", icon = icon("heart"), class = "btn-info")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df <- data.frame(
    group1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B"),
    group2 = c("X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "X"),
    value = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35)
  )

  friendlyActServer("test", {
    if (input$event == "message") {
      result <- df %>%
        group_by(group1, group2) %>%
        summarise(total_value = sum(value))
    } else if (input$event == "warning") {
      # I still have no idea what a simple manipulate can produce warning
    } else if (input$event == "error") {
      df2 <- left_join(df, x, by = "123")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```